# Set Button text vertical align to center/middle?

Tags: css, sapui5

Hey I want to display the text of my button in the center of my button.
So is there a attribute I can change so that it's appears in the center?
Right now it's at the top border of my button.

I tried to use the padding-top attribute, but it looks different when using different browser like Firefox, IE, etc.

Is there a general solution to display the text in the center of a button?

Thank you for any hints!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have not shared the code i am assuming `30px` height of your button. Use this css in your button.

```
button{
   height:30px;
   line-height:30px;
}
```

and remove padding if any.

This will center align your text.

**EDIT : Sometimes the text is little bottom aligned from center for that you can also use this**

```
button{
   height:30px;
   display: inline-flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks I'm using 75px right now. But it works fine when using the same px for line-height as for the button height.

Comment: ya thats why i mentioned i am assuming...line-height increases the height of text only and if the height of outer div and inner text is same it will automatically comes in center :)

Comment: [doesn't work for me](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/z01x8Lj7/)

Comment: @gman have updated my answer and for your case you can use the second solution. It will work fine.

Comment: That is actually not centered either. It's too high. Apparently one way is like you said, set line height and height but you have to [subtract the border size](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/z01x8Lj7/).

Comment: well if its too high u can handle it by vertical align options on button that depends on your HTML structure.